# 2014 Commands out of sync - MySql query J4

Tags: mysql, joomla-4

I've come across this error when performing some database queries in my J4 site model:

```
    $db->setQuery((string)$query);

    try {
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
        Factory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($e->getMessage(),'danger');
        return false;
    }
```

Then I do some stuff with the output called $rows and then based on the result of this "stuff" (ie a ref_id) I try to update all the records that were returned in $rows using:

```
        $db     = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->clear();
        $query = ' UPDATE #__my_table_name SET state = 5, ref_id = '.(int) $ref_id.' WHERE user_id = '.(int) $user->id.' AND state = 1 ';
        $db->setQuery((string)$query);

        try {
            $result = $db->loadResult();
            return true;
        } catch (RuntimeException $e) {
            Factory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($e->getMessage(),'danger');
            return false;
        }
```

The "stuff" being done has nothing to do with the database, just tweeking some text files, so why is it saying I'm out of sync?  Is there a new step required here?  Any and all help greatly appreciated.  Cheers.

Comment: After your `UPDATE` query, I think you need to replace `$result = $db->loadResult();` with `$result = $db->execute();`

Comment: Ahhh, of course, as I don't really need the result a straight execute does the trick, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to post as a proper answer below and mark as accepted so other know the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended by @Lodder changing:

```
$db->loadResult();
```

to

```
$db->execute();
```

solved the problem.